# Wireless bridge for embedded ethernet switch

Tags: switches, embedded, ethernet, wifi

I'm building a robot which has an embedded 8 port ethernet switch on it (using a KS8997 controller IC). The reason for that is, that some components like the motor controllers are controlled via ethernet. So there is a CAT5 cable hanging from the robot that connects to my laptop.

I'm wondering if there is a simple solution to turn the wired robot into a wireless one using WiFi. Is it possible to connect a cheap "RJ45 to WiFi Bridge" to the uplink port on the switch?

Thanks for any hints!

Comment: any physical size requirements?

Comment: as small as possible ;) max area is like 150x100mm and max height about 25mm there may be an external antenna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you only need two wireless router/access points that can work as bridges. The cheapest ones have typically only one wireless interface and one wired interface, and they can be configured to just forward between the two interfaces (i.e. bridge them).

After configuring both (this is often called "wireless adapter mode" in the manufacturer's software & manuals), you connect one access point to the switch on the robot, the other to your laptop/home switch, and you're done.

The trick is to find access points that can work off low power, e.g. USB. (You don't want to replace the Ethernet cable with a power one after all ;) I myself have had success with the [Asus WL-330](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0014L4ZKK) from Amazon. A colleague bought a [TP-LINK Portable Wireless N Router](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007PTCFFW) last week and he says it has the same "bridge" functionality as the Asus, in addition to costing only 17EUR and using so little power that his Kill-a-watt can't measure it.

Hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the hints, I'll give the "TP-Link Nano" a try!